# how to delete record through primary key in android

Tags: android, primary-key, android-database

While deleting record through primary key, primary key get null value and record doesn't deleted.

Please look in to my code,

```
 dataBase.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_PARKSAL_TABLELIST, DbHelper.PARKSALE_PrimeryID+ "=" + primarykeytableid, null);
```

I want to delete whole row data with primary key as well. How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kai error ave che ?? @Shuchi Sheth

Answer (score 0):

Checkout that you are passing each parameters and is not null like primarykeytable id cannot be null.

Or you can try this

```
db.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_PARKSAL_TABLELIST, DbHelper.PARKSALE_PrimeryID+"=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the row with key is empty or null or your given value, We can delete the row using following,

```
String whereClause = DbHelper.PARKSALE_PrimeryID + " = ? OR " // For the value which you give
        + DbHelper.PARKSALE_PrimeryID + " = ? OR " // For empty values
        + DbHelper.PARKSALE_PrimeryID + " IS NUL"; // For Null values
String[] whereArr = new String[] {
        primarykeytableid, "''"
};

dataBase.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_PARKSAL_TABLELIST, whereClause, whereArr);
```